# parse json in custom list view base adapter

Tags: android

public class YourAdvertisement extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

String date[] = null;

String price[] = null;

String  type2[] = null;

String amount[] = null;
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    String url =uid + "&access_token=" + access_token + "&start=" + start + "&total=" + total + "&type=" + type + "&signature=" + hashkey;

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            // s is the response from the server
            //if success go to login page

            if (s.contains("{\"status_code\":100,\""))
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray leaders= json.getJSONArray("listing");

                    // ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(int i=0;i<leaders.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonas = leaders.getJSONObject(i);
                        date = jsonas.getString("date");
                        price = jsonas.getString("price");
                        type2 = jsonas.getString("type");
                        amount = jsonas.getString("amount");
                        items.add(date);
                        Log.d(date,"Output");

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourAdvertisement.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);

                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


                Intent intent = new Intent(YourAdvertisement.this, Tabbed.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }



    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(YourAdvertisement.this, "Some error occurred -> " + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //This is to hide the keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(YourAdvertisement.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);


}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return date.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_view_layout,null);

        TextView buyTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buyTextView);
        TextView buyValueTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buyValueTextView);
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);



        return convertView;
    }


}
```

}

how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .how to parse json into base adapter custom list view ? Here is my code.Can anyone correctmy code?thank and appreciate .

Comment: You are initializing an ArrayAdapter, then using an uninitialized customAdapter.

Comment: @lionscribe can you share the code?

Comment: You need to initialize listView also before access that

Comment: First get it working with static text, then worry about json.

Comment: can someone correct my code?

Comment: Make Model class for storing the json data.

Answer (score 0):

```
      ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
     (YourAdvertisement.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, 
      items);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

     Above place change the adapter class 
     Declare the CustomAdapter in Globle declaration 

      CustomAdapter cm;


      cm = new CustomAdapter (this,items);
      listView.setAdapter(cm);

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return date.length();
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_view_layout,null);


       TextView timeTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);

       timeTextView.setText(date[position]);

       return convertView;
    }
```